# Debugging dump file Call Stack has not much info

Tags: c++, debugging, mfc, runtime-error

Our customer reported a "Microsoft Visual C++ Runtime Library: Runtime Error!"
We received a dump file (.DMP) from them. I debugged it using Visual Studio 2013 but the Call Stack only has 5 lines:

```
[External Code]
myprogram.exe!AfxInternalPumpMessage() Line 153
myprogram.exe!AfxWinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance, HINSTANCE__ * hPrevInstance, char * lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) Line 47
myprogram.exe!__tmainCRTStartup() Line 263
[External Code]
```

All the lines only trace back to MFC code, and nothing to our source code.

What is the "[External Code]" referring to there?

Am I doing something wrong?
Thank you!

Actually, I just found out I can expand the [External Code] and it becomes like this:

```
user32.dll!_NtUserGetMessage@16()   
user32.dll!_GetMessageA@16()    
myprogram.exe!AfxInternalPumpMessage() Line 153
myprogram.exe!AfxWinMain(HINSTANCE__ * hInstance, HINSTANCE__ * hPrevInstance, char * lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow) Line 47
myprogram.exe!__tmainCRTStartup() Line 263
kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  
ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8() 
ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()
```

But still nothing from my source code.

Comment: Your source code most likely.

Comment: How come my source code sources are not showing up?

Comment: Depends on the exception handler creating the `.dmp` file. Also be sure to have the `.pdb` files from the same build as the `.dmp` file comes from.

Comment: This is a fairly typical call stack for any interactive application. The application is waiting for a message to arrive in its message queue. This is to be expected, since that is where a typical application spends most of its time. You need to debug another thread (the thread, that actually fails). It is not this thread.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try `windbg.exe`?
As @Blacktempel said, you need the `.pdb` files from your build.
That means every time you deliver your code to your customers, you have to keep the `.pdb` files(at least) for debugging.

You can reference this link below,
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff538042(v=vs.85).aspx